# How to use voice recognition in an Alexa Skill to personalize responses

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Is there a way I can use voice recognition to personalize responses in an Alexa Skill? I am creating an Alexa Skill where I want Alexa to generate responses based on the user who utters the command. Currently I'm thinking of simply configuring the app such that it asks the user who they are before responding to their command/question. However, this is a very naive approach, so I was wondering if there is a way Alexa can use voice recognition to figure out who is talking to it. Couldn't find anything useful online, so it would be great if anyone here who has done something similar could share their insights.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon is working on this capability, and is current accepting requests to receive more information as it is released. You can sign up with Amazon to receive information [here](http://dev.amazonappservices.com/alexa-voice-profile.html).